# Deb package created using fpm but giving error while depackaging

Tags: packaging, deb

I created a deb package of https://github.com/manojgudi/sandhi using fpm. The package was successfully created but on de-packaging on another system it gives me the following error :

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 8 package 'sandhi':
`Depends' field, reference to `git-core':
implicit exact match on version number, suggest using `=' instead
dpkg: error processing sandhi-1.0_amd64.deb (--install):
parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 8 package 'sandhi':
`Depends' field, reference to `git-core': version contains ` '
Errors were encountered while processing:
sandhi-1.0_amd64.deb
```

I am new to this. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Could you post output of `lintian sandhi-1.0_amd64.deb`

Comment: Post the referenced file, namely `/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control`.

Answer (score -1):

You should follow these steps, may work for you.

1) .deb file install in root path only so root path command: `sudo su`

2) then find the your your .deb file in which folder

3) using `ls` command show the particular folder files.

4) then find your .deb package file.

5) deb package command as `dpkg -i ./your_file_name` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

6) may be work for you. I am install virtualbox.deb file in my ubuntu(LInux-14.04v).

Comment: It does not answer the question, the OP has already used `dpkg` in proper way, the error clearly shows that there is some dependency problem and some parsing problem.